# Django 2.1 Foreign Key set value based on previous form field value which is submitted to database

Tags: django

iam having a problem to assign my foreign key value to the first form field value. Model Startup is parent and Model Team is Child with a foreign key related to Startup model and the value of startup_name must be assigned to the startup foreign key field. however, the Team Model is a dynamic fields where multi Team members is inserted to the model and foreign key is only one field.
i need help to get it right taking in place that am new to django programming

forms.py:

```
from .models import *
from django import forms

class StartupNameForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ['startup_name',]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db  import models

class Startup (models.Model):
    startup_name=models.CharField('Startup Name', max_length = 100, unique = True)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.startup_name

class Team (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField ( 'Name' , max_length = 100 )
    position = models.CharField ( 'Position' , max_length = 100 )
    startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete = models.CASCADE, to_field = 'startup_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def str_dashboard(request) :
    return render ( request , 'str_dashboard.html' )

def startup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StartupNameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('str_team')
    else:
        form = StartupNameForm()
    return render(request, 'application/str_name.html', {'form': form})

def team(request, self):
    TeamFormset = modelformset_factory(Team, fields = ('name','position'), extra = 1)
    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = TeamFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit = False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.Team.startup = request.session['startup_name']
                instance.save()
            return redirect('str_dashboard')
    else:
        formset = TeamFormset ()
        return render(request,'application/str_team.html', {'formset':formset})
```

URLS.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path ( 'str_dashboard/' , views.str_dashboard , name = 'str_dashboard' ) ,
        path ( 'application/' , views.startup, name = 'str_name' ) ,
        path ( 'application-1/' , views.team, name = 'str_team' ) ,
    ]
```

Server Session:

```
     System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
     July 19, 2019 - 18:51:49
     Django version 2.1.8, using settings 'sourcing.settings'
     Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
     Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
     [19/Jul/2019 18:51:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 718
     [19/Jul/2019 18:51:55] "GET /str_login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2205
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:02] "POST /str_login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:02] "GET /str_dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11222
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:05] "GET /application/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1464
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:13] "POST /application/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:14] "GET /application-1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4687
     Internal Server Error: /application-1/
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-                           packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
         response = get_response(request)
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
         response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
         response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,          **callback_kwargs)
       File          "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled1\sourcing\startups\views.py", line 30,          in team
         if formset.is_valid():
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 301, in is_valid
         self.errors
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 281, in errors
         self.full_clean()
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 322, in full_clean
         for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 110, in total_form_count
         return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT],          self.absolute_max)
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
       File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-         packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 92, in management_form
         code='missing_management_form',
     django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is          missing or has been tampered with']
     [19/Jul/2019 18:52:36] "POST /application-1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 93454
```

Comment: i have edited my code and assigned the foreign key to the related field and after commit save i am trying to automatically assign the foreign key field to the startup_name passed from the previous form. can somebody tell me what am doing wrong.

Comment: it seems like my request is so impossible or it is not possible to be done with python

Answer (score 1):

many thanks to Farhani Walid and all credit goes to him who helped in getting this problem solved, i am posting below the final code sets for future use by others who are having the same problem. please note in my case i didnt had to import the session but in your case i recommend to do in case your IDE require it

```
     from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
```

forms.py:

```
    from .models import *
    from django import forms

    class StartupNameForm (forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
         model = Startup
         fields = ['startup_name',]
```

models.py:

```
     from django.db  import models

     class Startup (models.Model):
         startup_name=models.CharField('Startup Name', max_length = 100)


         def __str__(self) :
             return self.startup_name

     class Team (models.Model):
         name = models.CharField ( 'Name' , max_length = 100 )
         position = models.CharField ( 'Position' , max_length = 100 )
         startup = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

         def __str__(self):
             return self.name
```

views.py:

```
     from django.forms import modelformset_factory
     from .decorators import str_required
     from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
     from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
     from .forms import *


     @login_required ( login_url = 'str_login' )
     @str_required
     def str_dashboard(request) :
         return render ( request , 'str_dashboard.html' )


     def startup(request):
         if request.method == 'POST':
            form = StartupNameForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 saved_startup_object = form.save()
                 request.session['saved_startup_object'] = saved_startup_object.id
                 return redirect('str_team')
         else:
             form = StartupNameForm()
             return render(request, 'application/str_name.html', {'form': form})

     def team(request):
         stored_startup_object = request.session['saved_startup_object']
         TeamFormset = modelformset_factory(Team, fields = ('name','position'), extra = 1)
         if request.method=='POST':
             formset = TeamFormset(request.POST)
             if formset.is_valid():
                 team_startup = None
             if stored_startup_object is not None:
                 team_startup = Startup.objects.get(id=stored_startup_object)
                 instances = formset.save(commit = False)
                 for instance in instances:
                     instance.startup = team_startup
                     instance.save()
             return redirect('str_dashboard')
         else:
             formset = TeamFormset ()
             return render(request,'application/str_team.html', {'formset':formset})
```

urls.py:

```
     from django.urls import path
     from . import views

     urlpatterns = [

         path ( 'str_dashboard/' , views.str_dashboard , name = 'str_dashboard' ) ,
         path ( 'application/' , views.startup, name = 'str_name' ) ,
         path ( 'application-1/' , views.team, name = 'str_team' ) ,

     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i fully understand what you want to do here, you want to assign the startup.id which was created in the first view as a foreign key of the team model which is created in the second view, in that case you may want to pass the value of the startup from the first view to the second view and in order to do that what i have used when i was in that situation is the session.
You store the startup id in the session as a variable and you interpret it on the second view dont't forget to import Session like that:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
```

You can get all the required information about session from the docs here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

EDIT:

Try to update your view like this and give me the output on the server log

```
def startup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StartupNameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            saved_startup_object = form.save()
            request.session['saved_startup_object'] = saved_startup_object.id
            return redirect('str_team')
    else:
        form = StartupNameForm()
        return render(request, 'application/str_name.html', {'form': form})

def team(request):
    stored_startup_object = request.session['saved_startup_object']
    TeamFormset = modelformset_factory(Team, fields = ('name','position'), extra = 1)
    if request.method=='POST':
        formset = TeamFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
        team_startup = None
        if stored_startup_object is not None:
            team_startup = Startup.objects.get(id=stored_startup_object)
            instances = formset.save(commit = False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.Team.startup = team_startup
                instance.save()
        return redirect('str_dashboard')
    else:
        formset = TeamFormset ()
        return render(request,'application/str_team.html', {'formset':formset})
```